# passing data from authentication cookie to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using an authentication cookie passed between websites on the same domain.  The cookie contains some user info and page info (the accession number). The design goal is for the user to click a button on the referring website, and it will launch a second website, authenticate based on the cookie, and do some useful stuff with the accession number.  I got most of this built, including getting the authentication passed and properly parsed out on the receiving system.

The problem I am having is that I can't get the data within the cookie into the javascript on the page. It seems when i launch website2 from website1, $(document).ready() is not fired after the page_load event (which handles the cookie parsing).  Also I tried using a literal to post the javascript code, it's never fired (seemingly it places it after the client side stuff is executed.

What I really want to do is call a javascript function getResults(accnum) using this data.

I have this code on the page_load event:

```
        if (userdata != null)
        {
            accnum = userdata[4];
        }
        if (accnum != String.Empty)
        {
            //HttpCookie accnumcookie = new HttpCookie("accnum", accnum);
            //this.Context.Response.Cookies.Set(accnumcookie);
        }
    }
```

When I run the .Set function, I'm not really sure of the innards and details, but long story short, the cookie is set but does nothing.

This is the document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var accnum = new String();
    accnum = GetCookie('accnum');
    if (accnum != null) {
        document.cookie = 'test=testz';
        var srch = document.getElementById('crit'); 
        srch.style.display = 'none';

        getResults('', 'accnum', accnum);
     }
```

Comment: is what you are trying to do not possible from server side?

Comment: I'd like to be able to fire a javascript function passing in that variable accnum.  I'd have to recreate a bunch of code server side but it may be possible.